# Path problem using Object as parameters in Vue router-link

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuetify.js

I have created a

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'casa', params: {casa: item ,codCasa:item.cod_Casa} }">{{ item.cod_casa }}</router-link>
```

but now a have a problem with path. Cannot have a clear url.

`item` 
is an object and then url is `http://localhost:8080/casa/%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

In routes i have

```
{
      path: "/casa/:casa",
      name: "casa",

      component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "./components/Casa/Casa.vue"),
      props: true
    },
```

If i use path: `"/casa/:codCasa"` it says codCasa is not defined.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in your path just `codCasa` and get the object inside your component.

Vue Roter allows [props](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html), so we can do something like:

```
    {
      path: "/casa/:casa",
      name: "casa",

      component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "./components/Casa/Casa.vue"),
      props: { casa: { id: 1, name: 'Casa 1' } }
    },
```

Where `casa` is defined as prop inside the component

But it looks like the object `casa` is dynamic and thats why I recommend the first way, using just the ID in the path and waiting a prop called `codCasa` in your component. Pay attention about the type used to the prop.

If you really need to pass the entire object and don't want to get it from backend inside the component, think about using just a child component without a new route.

Comment: casa is dynamic. I dont want to get the object again ...and  <template v-for="(item, index) in casas">  is constructing the router link ...<router-link :to="{ name: 'casa', params: {casa: item ,codCasa:item.cod_Casa} }">{{ item.cod_casa }}</router-link>

Comment: the problem is just the url...i have all data i need

Comment: Right, so that's what I said. We usually don't pass objects in path parameters and if you really need to pass the entire object and don't want to get it from backend inside the component, think about using just a child component without a new route.